# Jquery ajax - which encoding/datatype causes incomplete post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i use ajax for my codeeditor. So the POST contains lot of coding-syntax to handle :

```
$.ajax({  
  type: "POST",  
  url: "process.php",  
  data: dataString,  
  success: function() {  
    $('#messagebox').html("<div id='message'>hero!</div>");  
  }  
});
```

datastring is the val() i pull from a textarea, here it is. yes its random code from a file which get edited in the textarea:

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

// Import library dependencies
jimport('google.api.facebook');

class smartmech extends GmailApiFb
{
    function __construct(&$subject, $config)
    {
        parent::__construct($subject, $config);

        // define language
        $this->loadLanguage();
    }
?>
```

This is the process.php

```
            $code = $_POST['code'];             
            $myFile = "testFile.php";
            $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
            fwrite($fh, $code);
            fclose($fh);
```

THE RESULT is that the file gets created and saved like this:

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

// Import library dependencies
jimport('google.api.facebook');

class smartmech extends GmailApiFb
{
    function __construct(
```

**so it stops at the first "&". i have no clue why.**

Firebug -> Console analyses the post as completely sent, this is why i assume i have to en-/ or decode the ajax before sending.

Any hint is highly appreciated.

Thanks guys for your valuable time

**EDIT: 
Solution**

after further examing the POST from firebug, is saw the newline before starting with the value. (code is the key,

```
code=   
<?php
```

So i tried to use the mapping instead of a querystring:

```
  data: {code: kode}, //dataString,
```

this was the difference which makes the code working like a charm.
for completeness to make sense

```
var kode = editor.getValue();
var dataString = 'code='+kode;
```

getValue() is a custom function to get the val() from an element.

Anyone knows why this difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd be interested in seeing the actual post; particularly, if the parameters are being sent correctly. "data" should be either a serialized set of key:value pairs in the form of a query string (`myvar=foo&myothervar=bar`) or it can be a map ( `{ myvar: "foo", myothervar: "bar" }` ). If you are just grabbing a string from .val() like "foo" and trying to pass it, it might be poorly-formed upon sending. In other words, if you are grabbing "foo", it might be trying to send "`?foo=`" instead of "`?myvar=foo`".

I have to admit, that's a guess; I'm not in a good environment for testing AJAX right now.

Comment: I assume you meant .val() instead of .getValue? The latter is not a jQuery function. If so, make sure editor is a jQuery object and not just a DOM node. Is it possible that kode contains characters that need to be URI-encoded (mind you, I just remembered you're using POST rather than GET)?

Comment: hi, getValue is a custom function from our framework. sorry for being unprecisely.

Comment: Your hint with the post solved the issue, i will explain in the starting thread. thx 4 looking into my question